# How to approach a directional derivative as u varies

Tags: partial-derivative

> Find the maximum and minimum values of the directional derivative Duf at (1/2, 1)
>   as u varies for the function f(x,y)= x<sup>3</sup> -xy<sup>2</sup>-4x<sup>2</sup>+3x+x<sup>2</sup>y

What im not sure about is the phrase as u varies. I understand the formula for directional derivatives is Duf=∇f⋅u but don't understand what is meant by u varies.

My thoughts on how to do this question is letting the direction be in respect to u in (ux, uy) and I calculate the differential terms for x and y

I end up with (ux)(3x<sup>2</sup>-y<sup>2</sup>-8x+3+2xy) + (uy)(-2xy+x<sup>2</sup>)

Is this the right way of approaching this question? Also if I were to calculate the direction for u to give a maximum and minimum, how would I do so?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\nabla \vec{f}\cdot \vec{u} =\Vert f\Vert \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{f}$ and $\vec{u}$. So it is maximized if $\vec{f}$ and $\vec{u}$ are in the same direction while minimized if they are in opposite directions. So what I will do is evaluate $\vec{f}(1/2,1)$ and normalize it. Its normalization gives the max while the negative of the normalization minimizes the directional derivative.

Comment: Not quite. $\pm\nabla \vec f$, whether normalized or not, give the _directions_ of the max. and min. directional derivatives, but not the values of those derivatives.